# Does Salesforce impose a limit on the number of user licenses (salesforce or salesforce platform) an organization can purchase?

Tags: user, licenses, admin, userlicense

Does Salesforce impose a limit on the number of user licenses (salesforce or salesforce platform) an organization can purchase? is there any fix number or there is no limit. Can we purchase a large number of licenses and assign users to it in an org?
Also, if possible, can you please share the reference document for this limit.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, there is no limit. Salesforce will be more than happy for you to pay them more money.

About the only thing I'm aware of is that once a single company obtains a sufficient number of licenses, they'll get their own "pod". I.e. while instances like `na41` or `ap07` would normally service multiple Salesforce customers, large enough companies end up being the only customer on their particular instance (instance/pod are interchangeable, I believe).

The number of licenses where that will happen is not published, but is likely in the thousands.

Comment: I can just hear Benioff saying to his sales team -- "No, we don't want to sell <large number> of recurring subscriptions to organization X, tell the customer there's not a value proposition for so many users"